# Run a function on load and then every 10 minutes

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to execute a javascript function when the page loads and then not again for another 10 minutes. Even if user browses to another page? If they dont want the function to run again until the 10 minutes is up?

Answer (score 12):

Simply create the function you want to execute onload, call it once on DOM ready, and then use setTimeout()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething() {
        alert("Doing something here");
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        doSomething(); //Make sure the function fires as soon as the page is loaded
        setTimeout(doSomething, 600000); //Then set it to run again after ten minutes
    }
</script>
```

Edit:
Didn't notice the part about even if they're on another page. If it's another page on your website, you could set a cookie once the page loads, and include a timestamp for when the cookie was set. In the window.onload of the rest of your pages, you can then read that timestamp, and calculate whether 10 minutes have passed or not. If it has, call the function again.

Edit: 10 minutes is 600000 milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

> Even if user browses to another page?

Nope. Once your page closes, you no longer have control over what happens.

Comment: Just for reference of people looking at this now, years later. a cookie could hold the time of last run, then on page load you set the timeout to 10 minutes - (cookieStartTime - timeNow)

Answer (score 2):

```
function callfunction () {
  // do something
}
window.onload = function () {
  // Initial function call
  callfunction();
  setInterval(function () {
    // Invoke function every 10 minutes
    callfunction();
  }, 600000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to make something happen in the future.

But as soon as the user leaves your page those timers will be cancelled - the entire content will be unloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
setTimeout(alert('After 10 secs'),10000);
```

Comment: That's 10 seconds, not 10 minutes. ;o)

Comment: @patrick yep! 10 minutes would be `10 * 60 * 1000 = 600000` (10 mins * 60 seconds per minute * 1000 milliseconds per second.)

Answer (score 0):

If the user visits another website in the same tab, you're out of luck; once your webpage is closed the javascript dies.

However you're in luck if the user is just visiting other pages on **your** website. You can do this as follows... but it requires a fundamental redesign of your website. You'd have to use a framework which wraps all link-clicks in XHRs (XML HTTP Requests) and replaces the page with the new data, giving you the illusion that you are clicking links (which you are, but the browser never refreshes the page). This can be done with an iframe or not. This is how GMail works.

You could code such a framework yourself, but you're better off using a framework which has url-rewriting support for faking a history (or else your website won't work well with user histories).

To answer your question about the "every 10 minutes", use `setInterval(myFunction, 10*60*1000)` (which may have issues in some browsers due to optimizations).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use a server language, you can set a session variable at startup (startup date/time) and then, using setInterval, compare current time with startup date/time.

Answer (score 0):

you're required to save the state in a remote server.

this is your steps:

1. the javascript function loads, no matter where or when, it loads.
2. when loaded (the javascript fn) calls a remote server using a UNIQUEID, that can be obtained via cookies, or session variable, from the loggedin user id...whatever.
3. you send a request to a server using such UNIQUEID (via ajax, normally), your server will tell you if such process must start again or you should avoid it (a page jump as an example or a page refresh in a different browser using the same login, it depends on your business logic).
4. the response from step3 is used to execute/initialize the javascript loader or not.